# Entity Framework Core equivalent of SQL's "IN"

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 1.1, I can get all users which have a certain ClientId:

```
var users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.ClientId == 1)
```

But is it possible to return all users that have a ClientId that fall in a set? Something like

```
var users = _context.Users.Where(u => u.ClientId IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure this hasn't changed from EF not-core:

```
var posValues = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var qry = _context.Users.Where(u => posValues.Contains(u.ClientId));
```

(And if you look at the generated SQL you'll see this translated into an `IN` expression.)